# Trying to resolve three conditions for a bit column

Tags: t-sql

It seems like this shouldn't be hard to do but my TSQL knowledge is lacking. How do I resolve three conditions for a bit column? This is what I have but of course the compiler doesn't like the OR in the CASE.

To be clear, in the case of All I want both zero and one column values. Null will be excluded.

MyTable

```
Id  Name                LockedState    Deleted
12  Doe, John               0             1
14  Doe, Johnny             0             1
15  Fischer, Julia          1             1
16  Hemsworth, Christopher  0             1
17  Getty, Kristyn          1             1



SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Deleted = @Deleted
AND LockState = CASE
    WHEN @Assigned = 'ALL' THEN 0 OR 1
    WHEN @Assigned = 'Assigned' THEN 1
    WHEN @Assigned = 'UnAssigned' THEN 0
END
```

Desired Output for 'All'

```
12  Doe, John               0             1
14  Doe, Johnny             0             1
15  Fischer, Julia          1             1
16  Hemsworth, Christopher  0             1
17  Getty, Kristyn          1             1
```

Desired Output for 'Assigned'

```
15  Fischer, Julia          1             1
17  Getty, Kristyn          1             1
```

Desired Output for 'Unassigned'

```
12  Doe, John               0             1
14  Doe, Johnny             0             1
16  Hemsworth, Christopher  0             1
```

Comment: The logic for 'ALL' is flawed, you can't have both values assigned to single BIT value.  Should it be 1 or should it be 0?  Or should it be NULL?

Comment: I modified the OP. In the case of ALL I want BOTH zero and one.

Comment: I mean, that's my point.  You can't have both values in a single column in a single row.  Or do you want multiple rows?  It would probably help if you add your desired output.

Comment: I'm sorry. In my head I knew what I was after. Let me update the question with desired output but yes multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Deleted = @Deleted
AND (@Assigned = 'Assigned' AND LockState = 1
    OR @Assigned = 'UnAssigned' AND LockState = 0
    OR @Assigned = 'ALL')
```

or like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Deleted = @Deleted
AND LockState = CASE
    WHEN @Assigned = 'ALL' THEN LockState
    WHEN @Assigned = 'Assigned' THEN 1
    WHEN @Assigned = 'UnAssigned' THEN 0
END
```

Comment: WHEN @Assigned = 'ALL' THEN LockState....That's really cool. What does that do? Just rteturn the column regardless of the value?

Comment: @GPGVM Yes, that's it.